# Bogomolov-inequality reference of proof

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Where can I find a written proof of the bogomolov inequality using complex analysis (aka the existence of a ricci flat metric on semistable bundles)?

Comment: Which Bogomolov inequality for Rocco flat manifolds do you mean?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon For semistable vector bundles

Comment: For stable bundles one can start by proving the Kobayashi-Lubke inequality. If $(E,h)$ is a holomorphic bundle with Hermitian metric $h$ whose curvature tensor is $R$ over a manifold $X$ with Hermitian metric $\omega$, then we have $|R|^2 \omega^{n}/n! = (2 c_2(E,h) - c_1(E,h)^2) \wedge \omega^{n-2}/(n-2)! + | \operatorname{tr}_{\omega} R|^2 \omega^n/n!$. From this we get the K-L inequality, equivalent to the Bogomolov one here, when $(E,h)$ is Hermite-Einstein. That happens iff E is stable by Kobayashi-Hitchin. I don't know how this carries over to the semistable situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is written up in *Differential geometry of complex vector bundles* by Kobayashi (2nd. edition):

- **Theorem IV.5.7**: The Bogomolov (a.k.a. Kobayashi–Lübke) inequality holds on bundles that admit approximate Hermite-Einstein metrics.
- **Theorem VI.10.13**: On a projective variety, semistability is equivalent to the existence of approximate Hermite–Einstein metrics.

The book thinks that semistability should be equivalent to the existence of approximate Hermite–Einstein metrics on compact Kähler manifolds. I think this was an open problem at the time. My knowledge of the field is not up to date, but I think the problem is still open.